# Linkedin Oauth invalid_signature

Tags: zend-framework, oauth, linkedin-api

Getting following error when trying to send oauth request to linkedin. Tried changing all configuration settings on Linkedin Developer page, without luck.

```
Zend_Http_Response Object
(
[version:protected] => 1.1
[code:protected] => 401
[message:protected] => Unauthorized
[headers:protected] => Array
    (
        [Server] => Apache-Coyote/1.1
        [Www-authenticate] => OAuth realm="https%3A%2F%2Fapi.linkedin.com", oauth_problem="signature_invalid", oauth_problem_advice="com.linkedin.security.auth.pub.LoginDeniedInvalidAuthTokenException%20while%20obtaining%20request%20token%20for%20%3APOST%26https%253A%252F%252Fapi.linkedin.com%252Fuas%252Foauth%252FrequestToken%26oauth_callback%253Dhttp%25253A%25252F%25252Fsocialnucleus.org%25252Fwall%25252Flinkedin%25252Findex%25252Fformat%25252Fsmoothbox%25252Ftask%25252Fstream%2526oauth_consumer_key%253D753ndm4jkq5ug9%2526oauth_nonce%253D296db6c938b6b3a7af93bd01c37e4d5f%2526oauth_signature_method%253DHMAC-SHA1%2526oauth_timestamp%253D1409219193%2526oauth_version%253D1.0%2526scope%253Drw_nus%0AOAU%3A753ndm4jkq5ug9%7C%2A01%7C%2A01%7C%2A01%3A1409219193%3AKNkpSGf5VSdXkeLYVO0xW%2Fr6N%2BE%3D"
        [Content-type] => application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8
        [Content-encoding] => gzip
        [Vary] => Accept-Encoding
        [Date] => Thu, 28 Aug 2014 09:47:13 GMT
        [X-fs-uuid] => 2ad6973e6d8d8e13004a6ed9fc2a0000
        [X-li-uuid] => KtaXPm2NjhMASm7Z/CoAAA==
        [X-li-fabric] => PROD-ELA4
        [Transfer-encoding] => chunked
        [Connection] => keep-alive
        [X-li-pop] => PROD-ELA4
        [Set-cookie] => lidc="b=LB37:g=108:u=1:i=1409219233:t=1409305633:s=132873074"; Expires=Fri, 29 Aug 2014 09:47:13 GMT; domain=.linkedin.com; Path=/
    )

[body:protected] => 1aa...
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Start with the guide to debug API calls: https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/debugging-api-calls

It seems that the signature isn't being generated correctly. Use OAuth Test Console: https://developer.linkedin.com/oauth-test-console to generate the signature and the request URL.

Comment: Then how do I test generated signatures validity?

Comment: You can generate the signed url using the oauth console that means you dont need to test the generated signatures validity but make the required call using that signed url.